# How to get count of items with same ids which are not in adapter view

Tags: android-espresso

I have the case where multiple instances of an item are there and I want to count them. 
My view matcher is as follows:

```
 public static ViewInteraction onTestPanelView(){
        return onView(allOf(withId(R.id.myId), isDisplayed()));
    }
```

With the view matcher, I get the following error:

> com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException:
>   '(with id: is <2131427517> and is displayed on the screen to the
>   user)' matches multiple views in the hierarchy. Problem views are
>   marked with '****MATCHES****' below.

This is correct because I have the multiple instance of items with same id (R.id.myId). I want to write a method which returns me the count of the views matching my criteria. Please note - they are not in adapter view.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but potentially someone will find it useful.

From [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoStartGuide) you can find that:

> In the vast majority of cases, the onView method takes a hamcrest
>   matcher that is expected to match one — and only one — view within the
>   current view hierarchy. Matchers are powerful and will be familiar to
>   those who have used them with Mockito or Junit. If you are not
>   familiar with hamcrest matchers, we suggest you start with a quick
>   look at this presentation.

Below you can find an explanation with an example of finding exactly one view. I've adjusted my tests to do it. However there could be a workarounds like finding parent container and count views of some instance on it.

This [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30361345/955107) hasn't helped me.

Comment: Actually its possible by writing the ViewAction. You can write viewAction, pass the view matcher and count how many times it matches!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the condition you place in `onView()` into matcher and put a counter inside the matcher. Each time the matcher will match the item the counter should be incremented.

```
int counter = 0;

public static Matcher<View> withIdAndDisplayed(final int id) {
    Checks.checkNotNull(id);
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with item id: " + id);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            if ((view.getId() == id) && (view.getGlobalVisibleRect(new Rect())
                    && withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE).matches(view))){
                counter++;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}

public static ViewInteraction onTestPanelView(){
    return onView(withIdAndDisplayed(R.id.myId));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check official samples for Android Espresso :
Visit https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/samples/index.html