# Swipe through ViewPager and take screenshots

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to be able to test my viewpager which has dynamic (the number of pages is not known in advance) set of pages, execute some asserts and be able to take a screenshot.

Since the viewpager has dynamic set of pages, I can't tell in advance how many times I want to `swipeLeft()`.

So, I wrote a custom constraint:

```
/**
 * Moves to the left by one page.
 */
public static ViewAction scrollLeftUntilEnd() {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return isDisplayingAtLeast(90);
        }
        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "ViewPager scroll one page to the left";
        }
        @Override
        public void perform(final UiController uiController, final View view) {
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
            final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view;
            final int current = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

            final int size = viewPager.getAdapter().getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(i + 1, true);
                takeScreenshot("ViewPager_Cards");
            }
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
        }
    };
}
```

which I call like so:

```
onView(withId(R.id.myViewPager)).perform(scrollLeftUntilEnd());
```

but the page moves to the left only once.

Is that because the `ViewAction` returned by `scrollLeftUntilEnd()` can only perform once and not in a loop?

I could not use `repeatedlyUntil(swipeLeft(), ...);` because I need to take screenshots at every page.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(current + 1, true);
```

where `current` never changes.

Should it be

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(i + 1, true);
```

instead?

Comment: Good catch. However, even with that change I can't get a screenshot for each page, I only see screenshots for first and last page. I need to pause at each screen, get a screenshot and then swipe again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around my issue following [Jing Li's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37777065/1231910) approach and here is the snippet:

> public class CountHelper {
>
> ```
> private static int count;
>
> public static int getCountFromListUsingTypeSafeMatcher(@IdRes int listViewId) {
>     count = 0;
>
>     Matcher matcher = new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
>         @Override
>         protected boolean matchesSafely(View item) {
>             count = ((ListView) item).getCount();
>             return true;
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void describeTo(Description description) {
>         }
>     };
>
>     onView(withId(listViewId)).check(matches(matcher));
>
>     int result = count;
>     count = 0;
>     return result;
> }
>
> public static int getCountFromListUsingBoundedMatcher(@IdRes int listViewId) {
>     count = 0;
>
>     Matcher<Object> matcher = new BoundedMatcher<Object, String>(String.class) {
>         @Override
>         protected boolean matchesSafely(String item) {
>             count += 1;
>             return true;
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void describeTo(Description description) {
>         }
>     };
>
>     try {
>         // do a nonsense operation with no impact
>         // because ViewMatchers would only start matching when action is performed on DataInteraction
>         onData(matcher).inAdapterView(withId(listViewId)).perform(typeText(""));
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>     }
>
>     int result = count;
>     count = 0;
>     return result;
> }
> ```
>
> }

and I call this in my class like so:

```
final int count = getCountFromListUsingTypeSafeMatcher(R.id.myViewPager);
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
         onView(R.id.myViewPager).perform(swipeLeft());
         ...
         takeScreenshot("ViewPager_Cards");
    }
```