# How to get the list size from Espresso DataInteraction

Tags: android-espresso

I want to get the size of the list:

val list = onData(anything()).inAdapterView(listAdapterMatcher)

i saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30361068/assert-proper-number-of-items-in-list-with-espresso),  but i don't want to use it as assertion, i need to find it dynamically.

is there a way to get the list size?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `onData` to get the count.

You can just get the view and get the count.

```kotlin
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val activityScenarioRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun getAdapterViewCount() {
        activityScenarioRule.scenario.onActivity { 
            println(it.findViewById<AdapterView<MyAdapter>>(R.id.my_adapter_view).count)
        }
    }
```