# android espresso : total count of elements with same rid not in adapter view

Tags: android-espresso

I am trying to get the count of elements with same rid

The solutions here [How to get count of items with same ids which are not in adapter view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430500/how-to-get-count-of-items-with-same-ids-which-are-not-in-adapter-view) is not helping me.

```java
static int counter = 0;
public static Matcher<View> withIdAndDisplayed(final int id) {
    Checks.checkNotNull(id);
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with item id: " + id);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            if ((view.getId() == id) && (view.getGlobalVisibleRect(new Rect())
                    && withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE).matches(view))){
                counter++;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I see you trying to get child view count which is not an adapterView. 
See this one https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-test-kit-discuss/avLaBnBWr70

**Original answer:**

Are you using RecyclerView?

I used below code in my tests to get the RecyclerView size.

```
 public static Matcher<View> withRecyclerViewSize(final int size) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(final View view) {
            final int actualListSize = ((RecyclerView) view).getAdapter().getItemCount();
            LOGD(TAG, "RecyclerView actual size " + actualListSize);
            return actualListSize == size;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(final Description description) {
            description.appendText("RecyclerView should have " + size + " items");
        }
    };
}
```

Usage: `onView(withId(R.id.resource_id)).check(matches(withRecyclerViewSize(expectedSize)));`

In this case `resource_id` is RecyclerView.

There are few examples here: https://gist.github.com/chemouna/00b10369eb1d5b00401b.