# How to count the child with same id within ListView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, android-espresso

I have a ListView and it has multiple Linearlayout. 
                (1)LinearLayout
                     ->FrameLayout
                          -> RelativeLayout
                                 ->ImageView
                (2)LinearLayout
                      ->FrameLayout
                           -> RelativeLayout
                                  ->ImageView

How can I count the number of ImageView?  All of them have same id

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318086/android-espresso-total-count-of-elements-with-samerid-not-in-adapter-view

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Custom Matchers -
public final class CustomMatchers {

```
public static Matcher<View> childAtPosition(
        final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int position) {

    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("Child at position " + position + " in parent ");
            parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
            return parent instanceof ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                    && view.equals(((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(position));
        }
    };
}
```

}

Use it in your test case -

```
ViewInteraction textView9 = onView(
                allOf(withText("ViewName"),
                        CustomMatchers.childAtPosition(
                          CustomMatchers.childAtPosition(withId(R.id.view)id), 1), 0), isDisplayed()))
```